# PTX kernel name mangling

Tags: cuda

I cannot link my Cuda program when a kernel is compiled from `ptx` file.

**main.cu:**

```
extern 
__global__ void kernel(int, float*);

int main()
{
    ...
    kernel<<<...>>>(...);
    ...
}
```

**kernel.cu**

```
__global__
void kernel(int n, float* p)
{
    ...
}
```

If I compile like below, I have no problems and I get an executable:

```
nvcc -dc main.cu kernel.cu --gpu-architecture=sm_70
nvcc -dlink main.o kernel.o --gpu-architecture=sm_70 -o dlink.o
g++ dlink.o main.o kernel.o -lcudart
```

If I compile like below (by generating `ptx`), I get errors:

```
nvcc -ptx kernel.cu --gpu-architecture=sm_70
nvcc -dc main.cu kernel.ptx --gpu-architecture=sm_70
nvcc -dlink main.o kernel.o --gpu-architecture=sm_70 -o dlink.o
g++ dlink.o main.o kernel.o -lcudart
```

Error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_0000b5ce_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4789): undefined reference to `kernel(int, float*)'
tmpxft_0000b5ce_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x497e): undefined reference to `kernel(int, float*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am following an example from `CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf`.

What do I need to do to fix the error?

(This is CUDA 10.2).

Comment: compiling to ptx (`-ptx`) is not a supported avenue for use of the kernel with a program that is using the CUDA runtime API (which is what your program is doing).  So use the first method.  (this is not resulting from name mangling)

Comment: I actually want to tweak the ptx, cause I am not happy with it

Comment: That's generally not supported with the runtime API compilation path, and you should use the driver API methodology instead.  Take a look at the comparison between `vectorAdd` and `vectorAddDrv` sample codes.  Using the driver API, you can write your own PTX if you wish.

Comment: I would also point out that if you are "not happy" with the PTX, it may be good to know that the PTX is not actually what the machine executes.  The CUDA compilation flow passes PTX through an additional compilation stage (via the `ptxas` tool, which is an optimizing compiler) and this can result in underlying SASS code that looks very different from the PTX.  The GPU actually executes SASS code, not PTX.  PTX is an intermediate (or source) representation of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write your own PTX (or modify PTX), the proper CUDA methodology to use is the CUDA driver API and associated compilation flow.

The CUDA `vectorAddDrv` [sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition-driver-api) has all the plumbing and workflow that you need.